# Pass vector by reference to constructor of class

Tags: c++, class, oop, pointers, vector

I have a class called `test` with which I want to associate a large vector with in the order of million elements. I have tried doing this by passing a pointer to the constructor:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class test{
public:
    vector<double>* oneVector;
    test(vector<double>* v){
        oneVector = v;
    }
    int nElem(){return oneVector->size();}
};

int main(){
    vector<double>  v(1000000);
    cout << v.size() << endl;
    vector<double>* ptr;

    test t(ptr);
    cout << t.nElem()<< endl;

    return 0;
}
```

However, this results in a `Segmentation Fault:11`, precisely when I try to do `t.nElem()`. What could be the problem?

Comment: Recompile with `-Wall`, and your compiler will tell you what's wrong.

Comment: What do you think the pointer points to?

Comment: @immibis Nothing. I just realized that. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is C++, don't work with raw pointers if you don't absolutely need to. If the goal is to take ownership of a `std::vector` without copying, and you can use C++11, make your constructor accept an r-value reference, and give it sole ownership of the `std::vector` that you're done populating with `std::move`, which means only `vector`'s internal pointers get copied around, not the data, avoiding the copy (and leaving the original `vector` an empty shell):

```
class test{
public:
    vector<double> oneVector;
    test(vector<double>&& v):oneVector(std::move(v)){
    }
    int nElem(){return oneVector.size();}
};

int main(){
    vector<double>  v(1000000);
    cout << v.size() << endl;

    test t(std::move(v));
    cout << t.nElem()<< endl;

    return 0;
}
```

If you really want a pointer to a `vector` "somewhere else", make sure to actually assign `ptr = &v;` in your original code. Or `new` the `vector` and manage the lifetime across `test` and `main` with `std::shared_ptr`. Take your pick.

Answer (score 2):

`ptr` is not initialized.  What you "want" to do is:

```
test t(&v);
```

However, I think you'd be better suited with references here (it's in the title of your question after all!).  Using references avoids unnecessary syntax (like `->` over `.`) which just unnecessarily hinder the reading of the code as written.

```
class test
{
   std::vector<double>& oneVector;

   public:
      test(vector<double>& v) : oneVector(v) {}

       size_t nElem() const { return oneVector.size(); }
};
```

Comment: Thank you. I can't believe I missed something this simple. But thank you for the suggestion. I tried it, but I get the following while compiling `error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'test'`

Comment: Sounds like you didn't change the signature of the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

`ptr` is an uninitialized pointer. This unpredictable value gets copied to `t.oneVector`. Dereferencing it is undefined behavior.

You need your pointer to actually point at a valid vector.

Comment: The program already has UB when you attempt to copy the pointer (cf. [dcl.init]/12).

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to give your pointer the desired value, namely the address of the vector:

```
vector<double>* ptr = &v;
//                 ^^^^^^
```

In your code, `ptr` remains uninitialized, and your program has undefined behaviour.