# Initializing a member std::vector variable of a class that is a reference in c++

Tags: visual-c++, reference, stdvector

The parent class has this variable:

```
AutoAssignActionVector vAutoAssignActions = dlgSettings.AutoAssignActions();
```

... where `AutoAssignActionVector` is: `using AutoAssignActionVector = std::vector<S_MWB_AUTO_ASSIGN_ACTION>;`.

Now, I want to pass this vector *as a reference* into another class, because the other class needs to modify its properties.

So, I added this variable to the other class:

```
AutoAssignActionVector &m_vAutoAssignActions;
```

My problem is that it won't compile. At the moment the child constructor is:

```
CChristianLifeMinistryAutoAssignSelectNamesDlg::CChristianLifeMinistryAutoAssignSelectNamesDlg(CWnd* pParent /*=nullptr*/)
    : CDialogEx(IDD_DIALOG_OUR_CHRISTIAN_LIFE_AND_MINISTRY_AUTO_ASSIGN_SELECT_NAME, pParent)
{

}
```

I understandably get a error:

> error C2530: `CChristianLifeMinistryAutoAssignSelectNamesDlg::m_vAutoAssignActions`: references must be initialized

I understand why the error is displayed. But I can't change the constructor to:

```
CChristianLifeMinistryAutoAssignSelectNamesDlg::CChristianLifeMinistryAutoAssignSelectNamesDlg(CWnd* pParent /*=nullptr*/, AutoAssignActionVector &vAutoAssignActions)
    : CDialogEx(IDD_DIALOG_OUR_CHRISTIAN_LIFE_AND_MINISTRY_AUTO_ASSIGN_SELECT_NAME, pParent)
    , m_vAutoAssignActions(vAutoAssignActions)
{

}
```

... because then I get another error:

> error C2548: `CChristianLifeMinistryAutoAssignSelectNamesDlg::CChristianLifeMinistryAutoAssignSelectNamesDlg`: missing default argument for parameter 2

How do I get around this issue? If it were a pointer I could use `= nullptr` but when it is a reference??

I see similar question and trying to establish if is answers my problem: [Pass vector by reference to constructor of class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34521622/2287576)

Comment: Absent the class definition and constructor declaration, my crystal ball is a bit blurry... but see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swap the constructor parameters:

```
class CChristianLifeMinistryAutoAssignSelectNamesDlg : public CDialogEx
{
  CChristianLifeMinistryAutoAssignSelectNamesDlg(
    AutoAssignActionVector &vAutoAssignActions,
    CWnd* pParent = nullptr);
};
```

Comment: Yep, that did the trick. Awesome.